# R: Find shortest geodesic path between 2 points of a 2-D point cloud

Tags: r, igraph, dijkstra, network-analysis, weighted-graph

I created the following graph with help of two functions written by Vincent Zoonekynd (you can find them [here](http://zoonek2.free.fr/UNIX/48_R/05.html#2)) (find my code at the end of the post).

[image: Points connected to their 3 neighbouring points]

In order to be able to explain what that neighbourhood graph and that parameter "k" is, which the [Isometric Feature Mapping](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/290/5500/2319) uses. "k" specifies how many points each point is directly connected to. Their distance is just the euclidian distance to each other. The distance between any point and its (k + 1)-nearest point (or any point farther away) is called "geodesic", and is the smallest sum of all the lengths of the edges needed to get there. This is sometimes much longer than the euclidian distance. This is the case for points A and B in my figure.

Now I want to add a black line showing the geodesic distance from point A to point B. I know about the command `segments()`, which will probably be the best for adding the line, and I know that one algorithm to find the shortest path (geodesic distance) is Dijkstra's Algorithm and that it is implemented in the package `igraph`. However, I'm neither able to have `igraph` interpret my graph nor to find out the points (vertices) that need to be passed (and their coordinates) on my own.

By the way, if k = 18, i.e. if every point is directly connected to the 18 nearest points, the geodesic distance between A and B will just be the euclidian distance.

---

```
isomap.incidence.matrix <- function (d, eps=NA, k=NA) {
  stopifnot(xor( is.na(eps), is.na(k) ))
  d <- as.matrix(d)
  if(!is.na(eps)) {
    im <- d <= eps
  } else {
    im <- apply(d,1,rank) <= k+1
    diag(im) <- FALSE
  }
  im | t(im)
}

plot.graph <- function (im,x,y=NULL, ...) {
  if(is.null(y)) {
    y <- x[,2]
    x <- x[,1]
  }
  plot(x,y, ...)
  k <- which(  as.vector(im)  )
  i <- as.vector(col(im))[ k ]
  j <- as.vector(row(im))[ k ]
  segments( x[i], y[i], x[j], y[j], col = "grey")
}

z <- seq(1.1,3.7,length=140)*pi

set.seed(4)
zz <- rnorm(1:length(z))+z*sin(z)
zz <- cbind(zz,z*cos(z)*seq(3,1,length=length(z)))

dist.grafik <- dist(zz)

pca.grafik <- princomp(zz)

x11(8, 8)
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot.graph(isomap.incidence.matrix(dist.grafik, k=3), pca.grafik$scores[,1], pca.grafik$scores[,2],
           xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", cex = 1.3)
legend("topright", inset = 0.02, legend = "k = 3", col = "grey", lty = 1, cex = 1.3) 
segments(x0 = -8.57, y0 = -1.11, x1 = -10.83, y1 = -5.6, col = "black", lwd = 2, lty = "dashed")
text(x = -8.2, y = -1.4, labels = "A", font = 2, cex = 1.2)
text(x = -11, y = -5.1, labels = "B", font = 2, cex = 1.2)
```

Comment: Is your question plot related (in the sense that you don't know how to show black lines on your graph) or is it a network-related challenge (in the sense that you ask how to recode Dijkstra's Algorithm without igraph) or is it a question of how to get you graph interpreted by igraph ?

Comment: I edited my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code may help you, it use your data to create an igraph object with weight that are in your case, the euclidean distances between nodes.
Then you find the weighted shortest path which is returned by `sp$vpath[[1]]`. In the following example, it is the shortest path between nodes number 5 and 66.
I edited the code with the solution to plot from [mattu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5940920/mattu)

```
isomap.incidence.matrix <- function (d, eps=NA, k=NA) {
  stopifnot(xor( is.na(eps), is.na(k) ))
  d <- as.matrix(d)
  if(!is.na(eps)) {
    im <- d <= eps
  } else {
    im <- apply(d,1,rank) <= k+1
    diag(im) <- FALSE
  }
  im | t(im)
}

plot.graph <- function (im,x,y=NULL, ...) {
  if(is.null(y)) {
    y <- x[,2]
    x <- x[,1]
  }
  plot(x,y, ...)
  k <- which(  as.vector(im)  )
  i <- as.vector(col(im))[ k ]
  j <- as.vector(row(im))[ k ]
  segments( x[i], y[i], x[j], y[j], col = "grey")
}

z <- seq(1.1,3.7,length=100)*pi

set.seed(4)
zz <- rnorm(1:length(z))+z*sin(z)
zz <- cbind(zz,z*cos(z)*seq(3,1,length=length(z)))

dist.grafik <- as.matrix(dist(zz))
pca.grafik <- princomp(zz)

isomap.resul <-  function (d, eps=NA, k=NA) {
  a <- isomap.incidence.matrix(d, eps, k)
  b <- dist.grafik
  res <- a * b
  return(res)
}

a <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(isomap.resul(dist.grafik, k=3), 
                                 mode = c("undirected"), weight = TRUE)
sp <- shortest_paths(a, 5, to = 66, mode = c("out", "all", "in"),
                     weights = NULL, output = c("vpath", "epath", "both"),
                     predecessors = FALSE, inbound.edges = FALSE)

path <- sp$vpath[[1]] 

x11(8, 8)
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot.graph(isomap.incidence.matrix(dist.grafik, k=3), pca.grafik$scores[,1], pca.grafik$scores[,2],
           xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", cex = 1.3)
legend("topright", inset = 0.02, legend = "k = 3", col = "grey", lty = 1, cex = 1.3) 
segments(x0 = -8.57, y0 = -1.11, x1 = -10.83, y1 = -5.6, col = "black", lwd = 2, lty = "dashed")
text(x = -8.2, y = -1.4, labels = "A", font = 2, cex = 1.2)
text(x = -11, y = -5.1, labels = "B", font = 2, cex = 1.2)

for(i in 2:length(path)){
  aa <- pca.grafik$scores[path[i-1], 1]
  bb <- pca.grafik$scores[path[i-1], 2]
  cc <- pca.grafik$scores[path[i], 1]
  dd <- pca.grafik$scores[path[i], 2]
  segments(aa, bb, cc , dd, lwd = 2)
}
```

To run this script, you obviously need the package `igraph`.

To me it seems the shortest path according to the geodesic distance.
[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, starting at node no. 5 and terminating at node no. 91 will give a path from A to B. I named `sp$vpath[[1]]` `path`, to make the code for adding the path to the graph more readable: `for(i in 2:length(path)){segments(pca.grafik$scores[path[i-1], 1], pca.grafik$scores[path[i-1], 2], pca.grafik$scores[path[i], 1], pca.grafik$scores[path[i], 2], lwd = 2)}`. However, the path does _not_ seem to be the shortest. Therefore I'm wondering if I made a mistake or if `igraph` does at the end. Would you please add your impression? (I can't upload a pic in a comment, of course)

Comment: I modified the path manually a bit and resulted with this one: `path
 [1]  5  9 10 13 14 16 18 20 22 24 25 26 29 31 34 36 39 40 44 45 50 47 51 52 53 56 57 59 60 62 64 68 70 72 73 74 76 78 79 80 82 83 85 87 88 90 91`. This one is okay, I suppose, but, of course, no replicable solution.

Comment: I adjust the code from your solution to plot the segments and I add a picture of a plot. To me, it seems the shortest path (in term of euclidean distance on your geodesic space). Don't you think so ?

Comment: What the heck! This is precisely the path I posted seperately, some 3 hours ago! I've no clue why I had a different result... Thanks so much for your help, anyway!